# sql seach at root level in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this type of data.copied_from_prod_id column store prod_id value when new transaction are made.

```
business_id   prod_id   copied_from_prod_id
6882           8172         NULL
7565           8867         8172
7572           8874         8867
15156          16859        8874
18513          20405        16859
35348          38184        20405
```

Now i want to search data at root level 
e.g i am passing two business_id named as old_business_id and new_business_id as parameter.

old_business_id = 6882 and new_business_id = 18513 output should be

```
business_id   prod_id   copied_from_prod_id   latest_prod_id 
6882           8172         NULL                20405
```

now when old_business_id = 7565 and new_business_id = 35348 output should be

```
business_id   prod_id   copied_from_prod_id  latest_prod_id
7572           8874         8867                38184
```

now when old_business_id = 6882 and new_business_id = 35348 output should be

```
business_id   prod_id   copied_from_prod_id  latest_prod_id
6882           8172         NULL                38184
```

i can do it using while loop and cursor but i want result without looping and cursor

thanks in advance.

Comment: So you just need a self join

Comment: Yes ,I try it but i don't get result which i want.can you please help me..?

Comment: This is actually no join. This is independent queries in one line...

Comment: the logic is not cleared. old_business and new_business, how do you declare them ? based on what ? provide the full sample and desired results along with your actual query that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
declare @old_business_id int=6882 
declare @new_business_id int=18513 

select o.business_id,o.prod_id,o.copied_from_prod_id,n.business_id
from yourtable o -- o for old
cross join yourtable n -- n for new
where o.business_id=@old_business_id
and n.business_id=@new_business_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
DECLARE @old_business_id INT = 7565;
DECLARE @new_business_id INT = 35348;

WITH OldBusinessData
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM data
    WHERE business_id = @old_business_id
    )
    ,NewBusinessData
AS (
    SELECT prod_id
    FROM data
    WHERE business_id = @new_business_id
    )
SELECT *
FROM OldBusinessData
    ,NewBusinessData
```